# WPF AvalonDock make DocumentHeader tab flash Binding to Dependency Property

Tags: wpf

Newbie to WPF. I am attempting to make the tab flash of an AvalonDock DocumentHeader when a dependency property value is updated 'HasProblem' is set to true. Below is a code sample I understand that I need to create a DocumentHeaderTemplate and use DataTemplate.Triggers, perhaps a DataTrigger bound to HasProblem but am really unsure on implementation steps. Also if anyone could recommend a comprehensive video tutorial on WPF that perhaps covers some of the techniques that would be employed to achieve the flashing tab I would be very grateful.

```
<Window x:Class="AirportTab.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AirportTab"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:AirportCodeDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Click="OnToggleErrorClick">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding HasProblem}" ContentStringFormat="HasProblem={0}. Click to change" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

        <ad:DockingManager Grid.Row="1">

            <ad:LayoutRoot>
                <ad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                        <ad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                            <ad:LayoutDocument Title="Airport Code">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding View}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ad:LayoutDocument>
                        </ad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    </ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                </ad:LayoutPanel>
            </ad:LayoutRoot>
        </ad:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public class AirportCode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Operational { get; set; }
}

public class AirportCodeDataSource : DependencyObject
{
    public AirportCodeDataSource()
    {
        this.View = new ObservableCollection<AirportCode>
        {
            new AirportCode {Name = "JFK", Operational = true},
            new AirportCode {Name = "LHR", Operational = true},
            new AirportCode {Name = "LGW", Operational = true}
        };
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasProblemProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "HasProblem", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(AirportCodeDataSource));



    public bool HasProblem
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasProblemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasProblemProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AirportCode> View { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = new AirportCodeDataSource();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnToggleErrorClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AirportCodeDataSource.HasProblem = !this.AirportCodeDataSource.HasProblem;
    }

    public AirportCodeDataSource AirportCodeDataSource { get { return this.DataContext as AirportCodeDataSource; }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DataTemplate for the DocumentHeaderTemplate with little animation. refer the below code.

```
<ad:DockingManager Grid.Row="1" >
        <ad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.HasProblem}" Value="True">
                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange" Duration="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.HasProblem}" Value="False">
                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking"/>
                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
        <ad:LayoutRoot>
            <ad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <ad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                        <ad:LayoutDocument Title="Airport Code">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding View}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ad:LayoutDocument>
                    </ad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </ad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
            </ad:LayoutPanel>
        </ad:LayoutRoot>
    </ad:DockingManager>

 public partial class Window5 : Window
{
    public AirportCodeDataSource AirportCodeDataSource { get { return this.DataContext as AirportCodeDataSource; } }
    public Window5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new AirportCodeDataSource();
        this.AirportCodeDataSource.HasProblem = true;
    }
}

public class AirportCode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Operational { get; set; }
}
public class AirportCodeDataSource : DependencyObject
{
    public AirportCodeDataSource()
    {
        this.View = new ObservableCollection<AirportCode>
    {
        new AirportCode {Name = "JFK", Operational = true},
        new AirportCode {Name = "LHR", Operational = true},
        new AirportCode {Name = "LGW", Operational = true}
    };
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasProblemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "HasProblem",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(AirportCodeDataSource));



    public bool HasProblem
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasProblemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasProblemProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AirportCode> View { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Works great however if I undock the window then no longer works. Would that be due to the use of RelativeSource in binding declaration? How could the same be achieved when window is undocked? Thank you once more.